# Is the latest angular-fullstack-generator(v4.0.4) creating an angular 2 app instead of angular 1?

Tags: yeoman-generator, angular-fullstack, yo

I used the latest angular-fullstack-generator - v4.0.4 to create an app, but the client looks a lot like angular 2. It has components instead of controllers, it has classes, constructors etc. Have they stopped angular 1 now? Is there any option that I can set to create the app in angular 1? I do not know angular 2 yet.
Thanks!